# How can i access the console logs on chrome and assert if a line exists?

Tags: c#, selenium, console.log

Quite new to selenium, have been looking to find an answer to this question, but so far, all the times I have tried I was not able to get my desired result.

I followed other answers to access the chrome console logs but i get an exception:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
            
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Url = "https://test.test";
            var homePage = new HomePage(driver); //POM
            
            homePage.SignIn().Click();                
            homePage.Email("email");
            homePage.Password("pw");
            homePage.LogIn();
            var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
            foreach (var log in logs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());
            }
```

the exception is thrown on : `var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);`
System.NullReferenceException: '`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

I haven't been able to understand why it is thrown.

After that, i would like to assert the console logs to see if a specific entry is present. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a dirty workaround. If you get any good answer, please don't use mine.

Modify the default console.log method to store data in a newly introduced global variable:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
//Multiline string used for readability. Write it in single line
js.ExecuteScript("
    window.oldConsoleLog = window.console.log;
    window.logCalls = [];
    window.console.log = function(){
        oldConsoleLog.apply(window.console, arguments);
        window.logCalls.push(arguments);
    }
");
```

Now you'll be able to get all calls using the next code:

```
var calls = js.ExecuteScript("return window.logCalls");
```

If you need a cleanup:

```
js.ExecuteScript("delete window.logCalls;window.console.log = window.oldConsoleLog;")
```